# Find different email id's in a single row of dataframe via Regex and df.str.contains

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to analyze a dataset and I have run into a column which has multiple email id's in the same row here is an example which might be of help,

Suppose I have an email id column which contains multiple email id's in 1 row & they are separated by a semicolon:

```
a@gmail.com;b@rediffmail.com;c@harvard.edu;d@yahoo.com
```

what I want to do is if there is any other Email id apart from '@gmail.com' in that row I need to mark it as suspicious.

i.e. If there are 5 email id's and only 1 email id contains '@gmail.com' and the other 4 contain id's other than '@gmail.com' then I need to highlight that particular row in the data frame as suspicious.

trying to solve it through `df[].str.contains()` but no solution as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex and `numpy.where`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"Email": ["a@gmail.com;b@rediffmail.com;c@harvard.edu;d@yahoo.com", "a@gmail.com;b@gmail.com;c@gmail.com;d@gmail.com"]})
df["State"] = np.where(df["Email"].str.findall("(?<=@(?!gmail)).*?(?=;|$)"), "Suspicious", "Safe" )
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|  Row# |                         Email                       |      State   |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|     0 |   a@gmail.com;b@rediffmail.com;c@harvard.edu;d@y... |   Suspicious |
|     1 |   a@gmail.com;b@gmail.com;c@gmail.com;d@gmail.com   |   Safe       |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function to check emails for @gmail.com

```
def checkEmail(values):
    all_emails=values.split(';')
    susp=[]
    for email in all_emails:
        if('@gmail.com' not in email):
            susp.append(email)
    return susp
```

Applying the function to each row using lambda:

```
df['email'].apply(lambda row: checkEmail(row))
```